# Option Strict On Late Binding Error when passing parameter to Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a form that displays some basic information from a SQL table.  I want to print this information to a Crystal Report.  The function works great with Option strict off.  However, when I turn option strict on I get a "Option Strict On disallows late binding" error.

Here is the code block in question.

```
    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        Dim frm As New frmReportView
        frm.subject = "CPE Number - " & Me.tbCPE.Text
        frm.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        Dim rpt As Object = New CustPropertyEval
        rpt.SetParameterValue("cpe_no", Me.tbCPE.Text)
        SetDataSourceShowReport(frm, rpt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub
```

The late binding error is on the rpt.SetParameterValue("cpe_no", Me.tbCPE.Text) line.
If I comment this out and execute the application The code works fine but it forces the use to enter the cpe_no parameter.  I'd prefer to not be stuck with this.  Anyone have any idea why I can't pass that parameter with option strict on?  Also, frm is a Windows form that displays a crystal report and CustPropertyEval is the crystal report called which accepts one parameter - cpe_no.  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do "Dim rpt As Object" - that is causing your problem. Do "Dim rpt As CustPropertyEval" and Option Strict should stop complaining (assuming SetParameterValue is a method of CustPropertyEval).